# unlock macOS encrypted Volume on linux

Tags: disk-utility, unix, encryption, apfs, core-storage

How can i unlock a Partition that has been created and **encrypted** using Apples **Disk Utility** on a **linux machine**? 
There are 2 formats one can encrypt Volumes with **Disk Utility** :

- CoreStorage encrypted Volume
- apfs encrypted Container

I'm interested in both methods, if there are such.

Comment: See also: [Super User: How to mount APFS on Linux or Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1267291/425838)

Answer (score 3):

1. For accessing CoreStorage encrypted volumes, you can use the freely available `libfvde` software on Linux: https://github.com/libyal/libfvde
2. For APFS encrypted containers you can use either:

   1. The commercial software, "APFS for Linux by Paragon Software": https://www.paragon-software.com/us/business/apfs-linux/, or
   2. The freely available `apfs-fuse` software: https://github.com/sgan81/apfs-fuse

   Both of the APFS-file-system options above provide "read-only" access to your filesystem.

   Note that `apfs-fuse` is marked as "experimental", so your mileage may vary. However, since it is "read-only", it shouldn't do any harm to your data.

Comment: Note: according to the [FAQ at the bottom here](https://www.paragon-software.com/us/business/apfs-linux/#how_it_works), for Q "Can I write to APFS-formatted disks?", the answer is: **"Yes, the product provides APFS read-write access."** So, the commercial Paragon Software tool *does* seem to support read-write filesystem access, not read-only.

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can get Paragon Software's "APFS for Linux" here: https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/apfs-linux/ --> click on "Buy Now" at the top. The cost is currently $40.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I think you're overlooking the fact that this question is about encrypted file systems. Paragon only support write access to non-encrypted file systems.